# Bash script indenting command line

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Hi I have used the following script, which after it has run and exited, causes my command line to display no text when typing, and after each carriage return instead of starting a new line like

```
root@alix:~# 

root@alix:~#
```

I get

```
root@alix:~# root@alix:~# root@alix:~# root@alix:~#  etc
```

When using ctrl c I get

```
root@alix:~# 
            root@alix:~# 
                        root@alix:~#  etc
```

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

###
### Run command for given number of seconds then kill it
###

read -p "How long should I run for? ==> " count_secs
echo "Time specified: " $count_secs

if [ $count_secs -gt 0 ]
then
   ###
   ### number of seconds greater than zero
   ###

   watch -n 0.5 'iw dev wlan0 station dump | grep "signal avg" >> processmonitor.log' >>/dev/null & 

   ###
   ### assume that the PID of the command is $$
   ###
   my_PID=$!
   sleep $count_secs
   kill -15 $my_PID
fi
```

Thanks.

Comment: I run this script, but nothing from what you say didn't happend at me...

Comment: Anyway, if you want that your script to do what you proposed, i suggest you to use 1 instead 0.5 like argument for `watch`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code without the need to kill any process, after the end of the specified time (secs) it will exit.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
###
### Run command for given number of seconds then kill it
###
read -p "How long should I run for? ==> " count_secs
echo "Time specified: " $count_secs
# $SECONDS is a shell variable
# we can use it in conjuction with
# our user input 
while [ "$SECONDS" -le "$count_secs" ]
do
  # execute any commands here (put your code bellow and remove echo commands)
  echo `date +%r`
  echo "i am doing my work now"
  # sleep (in secs) before the next execution
  sleep 1
done
# when the count_secs elapses exit
exit 0
```

Comment: With `echo $(cmd)`, the echo and command substitution is pointless. Should just run `cmd` instead; no point in capturing the output only to output it again.

Comment: Both `echo` commands iside the loop are for demonstration purposes and will be replaced by the actual job as mentioned in code comments.

Comment: Thanks Stef, I ended implementing something quite similar. I am still not sure why I was getting those weird side effects.